# confused about Textview and Listview for displaying a list

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I tried a few different layouts to get deeper in possibilities and variances.
I started with an array to display the items in an listview that worked fine.

Now I wanted to display items that I got out of a database via JSON.

I get the following error: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView

I used the same XML-file, that worked before, here my `all_products.xml`:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:dividerHeight="1px">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In my java class I used the code that I used before for the array adapter, I changed only the parameter which should be displayed. Here part of my `AllProductsActivity.java`:

```
 private void processValue(ArrayList<String> result) {
    {
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AllProductsActivity.this, R.layout.all_products, result);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

result comes from my asynctask. here a snippet as well:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result.toString())
ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int n = 0; n < jsonArray.length(); n++)
{
    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(n);
    listdata.add(object.optString("nr"));
}
return listdata;
 protected void onPostExecute( ArrayList<String> result) {      
     pdLoading.dismiss();
     processValue(result);
 }
```

Why I get the error? And perhaps what about using only a Textview. As I was searching for the toppic, I found different threats where people using Textviews instead of Listview. 
EDIT: So it works I added another xml file, mytextview.xml

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/mytext"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:divider="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:dividerHeight="1px"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

and changed the adapterstatement to the following:

```
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AllProductsActivity.this,
                R.layout.mytextview,R.id.mytext  , result);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: You are adding the layout file all_products to the array adapter. That's wrong.
The Array Adapter expects a layout file representing a list item e.g. a layout file called list_item.xml which contains for example a TextView, where you can show the desired string for the list item...

Comment: why are you supplying all_products.xml while creating the adapter object? That is the parent layout in which your listview resides. Instead you should be creating a separate layout with a textview and supplying that layout in the parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use custom layout `R.layout.all_products` then Adapter don't know about the view to set the data from data list

so simply you need to tell the adapter , the ID of your text view to set data on .

```
 ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                     (AllProductsActivity.this,
                      R.layout.all_products,R.id.your_text_view_id, result);
//                                               ^^^^^^^^^ pass the text view ID
```

[ArrayAdapter (Context context, 
                int resource, 
                int textViewResourceId, 
                T[] objects)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T[]))

or

If you just want to display your data without any custom layout then can use in build android resource layout as

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,result);
```

Answer (score 1):

in Pavneet's first solution take care that:

**resource**: is the resource containing a textView not your xml file that contain the list itself (not R.layout.all_products)

**textViewResourceId**: the ID of the textView contained in the resource

Answer (score -1):

When instantiating your `ArrayAdapter`, the id you provide must be from a layout containing only a `TextView`. That is what the error `You must supply a resource ID for a TextView` means

Comment: " must be from a layout containing only a TextView" Not true. Pavneet's answer is correct.

Comment: Well, it is true when you use the constructor `ArrayAdapter(Context, int List).  The description for that parameter is: __The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use when instantiating views.__ But yeah, I guess my answer lacks some details and explanation

Comment: "Containing a textview" not "containing ONLY a textview".

Comment: you know you can edit your answer to  make it right , what are you waiting for ?